# Is there a need for another integration technique?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm being asked to calculate
$$I\triangleq\int_0^1\int_{e^{\large x}}^e{xe^y\over(\ln y)^2}\,dy\,dx\quad.$$

I got stuck on the indefinite inner one,
$$J\triangleq\int{e^ydy\over(\ln y)^2}\quad.$$
At first, I tried substitution with $u=e^y$, $u=\ln y$ and $u=(\ln y)^2$, none of them useful. Then I looked up [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) and it says $J$ can't be written in terms of elementary functions.

I assume there's an analytical way to find $I$ without $J$, otherwise the answer is what Wolfram said and the estimate from the [Double Integral Calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a) that $I\approx6.21799$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change limits. The region $0\leq x\leq 1$, $e^x\leq y \leq e$ can also be described as $1\leq y \leq e$, $0\leq x\leq \ln y$. Then
$$
\int_0^1\int_{e^{\large x}}^e{xe^y\over(\ln y)^2}\,dy\,dx\quad=\int_1^e\int_0^{\ln y}\frac{xe^y}{(\ln y)^2}\,dx\,dy=\frac12\,\int_1^ee^y\,dy=\frac{e^e-e}2
$$

Comment: Next time I'll know better than to not draw the freaking region. =D

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^x < y$ iff $ x < \ln(y)$, and so the above can be rewritten as 
$$
  \int_0^1 \int_{e^x}^e \frac{x e^y}{(\ln(y))^2}dydx
= \int_1^e \int_0^{\ln(y)} \frac{x e^y}{(\ln(y))^2}dxdy
= \int_1^e \frac{ e^y}{2(\ln(y))^2} (\ln(y))^2 dy
$$